# Compiler adding bitwise AND into expression tree with bit-shifting operation

Tags: .net, vb.net, expression-trees

I would expect the following code:

```
Dim i = 7, j = 5
Dim expr As Expression(Of Func(Of Integer)) = Function() i << j
```

to produce an expression tree of `LambdaExpression` with a single operation between the two variables `i` and `j`. Instead, the expression tree contains an additional bitwise `&` operation against `31`, as can be seen in the following DebugView:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`1[System.Int32]>() {
    .Constant<_visualizerTests.VB.Module1+_Closure$__0-0>(_visualizerTests.VB.Module1+_Closure$__0-0).$VB$Local_i << (.Constant<_visualizerTests.VB.Module1+_Closure$__0-0>(_visualizerTests.VB.Module1+_Closure$__0-0).$VB$Local_j &
    31)
}
```

or, [visually](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToCode):

[image: Expression Tree Visualizer screenshot]

The same operation gets introduced when a right-shift is used.

The C# compiler doesn't seem to have the same behavior -- neither left-shift nor right-shift operators cause the compiler to introduce any additional operations.

**Whey is this additional operation introduced?**

Comment: `Expression<Func<int>> expr = ()=> i << j; = 224 (=> i & 31 = 7 = j)`

Comment: [To prevent a shift by more bits than the result can hold, Visual Basic masks the value of amount with a size mask that corresponds to the data type of pattern.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/left-shift-operator#remarks)

Comment: @TnTinMn You missed the answer box by a few inches.

Comment: @TnTinMn Do you want to post your comment as an answer? Or should I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/left-shift-operator#remarks):

> To prevent a shift by more bits than the result can hold, Visual Basic masks the value of `amount` with a size mask that corresponds to the data type of `pattern`. The binary `AND` of these values is used for the shift amount.